# Unable to get save data event in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular6, ng2-smart-table

I am using `ng2-smart-table` for maintain data in my angular 6 app. As I seen in it's git and npm page. I have set my code like this way.

```
<ng2-smart-table 
[settings]="settings" 
[source]="characters"
(createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)">
```

I am able to load data in table by call API. But when I am not able to get save data event. For that I have set function like this.

```
onCreateConfirm(event) {
   alert("Clicked...");
}
```

I have set this function under the `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common issue, you need to set in the configuration object the confirmCreate property, like this:

```
export const settings= {
  delete: {
    confirmDelete: true,
    ...
  },
  add: {
    confirmCreate: true,
    ...
  },
  edit: {
    confirmSave: true,
    ...
  },
....
```